# Using Jupyter notebook on Spark on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am new to spark and AWS, I am trying to install Jupyter on my Spark cluster (EMR), i am not able to open Jupyter Notebook on my browser in the end.

**Context:** I have firewall issues from the place i am working, i can't get access to the EMR clsuter's IP address i create on a day-to-day basis. I have a dedicated EC-2 instance (IP address for this instance is white listed)  that i am using as a client to connect to the EMR cluster i create on a need basis.

I have access to the IP address of the EC2 instance and the ports 22 and 8080.
I **do not** have access to the IP address of EMR cluster.

Following are the steps that i am following:

1. Open putty and connect to the EC2 instance
2. Establish connection between my EC2 instance and EMR cluster
   ssh -i  publickey.pem ec2-user@*host name of the EMR cluster*
3. install jupyter on the spark cluster using the following command:
   pip install jupyter
4. Connect to spark:
   PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --no-browser --port=7777" pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0 --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 --executor-memory 6400M --driver-memory 6400M
5. Establish a tunnel to browser:
   ssh -L 0.0.0.0:8080:127.0.0.1:7777 ip-172-31-34-209 -i publickey.pem
6. open Jupyter on browser:

http://*host name of EMR cluster*:8080

I am able to run the first 5 steps, but not able to open the Jupyter notebook on my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it, as it involves setting up a test EMR server, but here's what should work:

Step 5:

```
ssh -i publickkey.pem -L 8080:127.0.0.1:7777 HOSTNAME
```

Step 6:

Open jupyter notebook on browser using 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Thank you @user1669710.  I had a similar problem.  From reading your answer I realized that I had skipped Step 5 because I was already ssh'd into to my server and I forgot that I needed to ssh into this port.

Answer (score -4):

You can use an EMR notebook with Amazon EMR clusters running Apache Spark to remotely run queries and code. An EMR notebook is a "serverless" Jupyter notebook. EMR notebook sits outside the cluster and takes care of cluster attachment without you having to worry about it.

More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks.html